# Finding minimum of function using its Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Say we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi(k) e^{ik \cdot x} dk 
$$
where $\psi$ is the Fourier dual of $f$. Say we further know that $\psi > 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and therefore by Bochner's theorem, $f$ is positive definite. Is there a method to deduce the minimum of $f$ using $\psi$?

Comment: since a positive definite function satisfies $|f(x)|\leq f(0)$, its minimum is $-\int\psi(k)\,dk$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you for your reply. I can see why this is a lower bound, but I cannot see why this would imply it to be a minimum. Could you elaborate?

Comment: you're right, it might not reach this lower bound.

Comment: In general the minimum can be any number strictly between $-1$ and $1=\int \psi$.